# Can I find Instagram Stories using the Public API?

Tags: instagram-api

Released here: http://blog.instagram.com/post/148348940287/160802-stories

No note of Stories being available via the API.

Comment: Not available, and my guess is that it wont be available via API since, stories are meant for 24hrs, having API will allow 3rd-party apps to cache the photos and allow viewing beyond 24hrs, which is not something Instagram wants.

Answer (score 6):

This is available now, but only if the user authorizes your app. The user's account would also need to be an Instagram Business Account.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/stories

Comment: hey @ryechus, I'm not sure from the documentation what this API returns.
Is it the stories of the business account itself have published or the ones of its followers?

Comment: The documentation is unclear, but my assumption is that it is for the business account itself. My reasoning is that the documentation doesn't list Instagram Public Content Access as a necessary permission. That permission is required to access public content on Instagram.

Comment: I've checked it and it only returns your own account stories.

Comment: Is there any API public to get message posted into the story and reply on after

Answer (score 5):

There is no public API, but you can get the story json data by going to instagram.com login with your account and paste this code in the console, it will output data in console

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     console.log(xhttp.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/reels_tray/", true);
xhttp.send();
```

(you have to do it from instagram.com and user logged in)

Comment: can i get the logged in users stories or just mine? and how can i get this in android?

Comment: just logged-in user's story, this is just a hack, it works only on browser, its not official API, it may stop working

Comment: This is stopped can you please help me to get story by other ways

Comment: @mehdiakbarian Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with two endpoints:

1. Perform a `GET` to `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1` to get the **user id** under `ROOT.graphql.user.id`
2. Perform a `GET` to `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/user/{user_id}/reel_media/` and be sure to use a valid **User-Agent** header (e.g.: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 Instagram 105.0.0.11.118 (iPhone11,8; iOS 12_3_1; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 828x1792; 165586599)`)

Remember this **only works for public profiles**, if you need something private (i.e. visible from your profile) you need to add two coockies to the requests: `ds_user_id` and `sessionid`. You can get those values with browser extensions (e.g.: [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en)). Also, never share these values with anyone because they represent your authentication to Instagram.

Lastly: yes, the stories you will get from the endpoint won't be shown as watched.

Comment: so in case, I follow a private IG account (assuming accepted).
whether or not your solution still works?
ps: my purpose is auto-fetch their latest stories (image, video, ...) from that private account

Comment: This is not going to work. However you can try loggin in with your browser and then use the cookies generated to perform an authenticated request. You can try postman interceptor to get the same excact call.

I've tried in the past, the result was that from my home network I couldn't refresh anything from the app anymore for few days (I guess they banned me)(but I could from mobile network) so, be cautious, they have a strict policy that you need to use your phone (or their client, more in general) to perform these actions.

Answer (score 0):

continue to run @krisrak's script.
You can run it when you use Chrome browser and installed extension "Chrome IG Story by Alec Garcia" then following step:
1. browsing https://i.instagram.com/api/v1
2. F12 to open DevTool window, go to tab Console
3. run the script of @krisrak above.

I'm sorry that Alec Garcia has announced he removed Chrome IG Story extension from the Chrome Web, see more from [his twitter](https://twitter.com/CaliAlec/status/1100826272010137600).
So if you has installed before you can use @krisrak help.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ig-stories-for-instagram/nilbfjdbacfdodpbdondbbkmoigehodg/related?hl=en